# Apollo useQuery not refetching data even though function is invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a `<HomePage/>` component where I fetch notifications for a user.

```
  const { data: notifications, error, refetch } = useQuery(GET_NOTIFICATIONS_FOR_USER, {
    variables: { userId: state && state.currentUser ? state.currentUser.id : null },
  })

  if (notifications) {
    console.log('from home', notifications)
  }
```

`notifications` and `refetch` are prop funneled to a `<NavHeader/>` and then to a `<Notifications/>` component.

**NavHeader**

```
<Notifications refetchNotifs={refetchNotifs} notifications={notifications} scrollPosition={scrollPosition} handleHideNotifications={handleHideNotifications} showNotifications={showNotifications} />
```

**Notifications**

```
const Notifications = ({ notifications, showNotifications, handleHideNotifications, scrollPosition, refetchNotifs }) => {


  const handleCloseNotifs = async () => {
    flipValues()
  }

  const [flipIsCheckedValues] = useMutation(FLIP_IS_CHECKED)
  const [ids, setIds] = useState(null)

  const flipValues = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await flipIsCheckedValues({
        variables: {
          ids: {
            ids
          }
        }
      })
      if (data) {
        console.log(data)
        refetchNotifs() // does not refetch ?? 
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.messsage)
    }
    handleHideNotifications()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (notifications) {
      setIds(notifications.filter((notif) => notif.isChecked === false).map((notif) => Number(notif.id)))
    }
  }, [notifications])


  return (
    <Overlay isShowing={showNotifications} currentTopPosition={scrollPosition} height={'94.5vh'}>
      <nav className={notificationStyles.nav}>
        <MdOutlineArrowBackIosNew onClick={handleCloseNotifs} />
        <h3>Activity</h3>
      </nav>
      <section className={notificationStyles.container}>
        {notifications && notifications.map((notif) => (
          <div key={notif.id} className={notificationStyles.notification}>
            <img className={notificationStyles.userImg} src={notif.fromUser.avatar} alt={notif.fromUser.avatar} />
            <p><strong>{notif.fromUser.userName}</strong> {notif.notificationType}. <span>{moment(notif.createdAt).fromNow()}</span></p>
            <img className={notificationStyles.postImg} src={notif.onPost.postContent} alt={notif.onPost.postContent} />
          </div>
        ))}

      </section>
    </Overlay>
```

in the `Notifications` component, which is an overlay over my `<HomePage/>` component I cannot get the `refetch` function to fire. I am running a mutation which flips a boolean value in my backend, and I need to then refetch all the notifications data so I can show the most updated version of the UI to the client. Any insight on how I can get this to successfully refire? The `useQuery` in the `<HomePage/>` that runs the initial fetch does not re run when I close the overlay because it is technically just a layer on top of the `<HomePage/>` component

Comment: Some additional debugging information would help.  Does `console.log(data)` output anything?  And what is `refetchNotifs`?  Is it just `refetchQueries` as returned from the hook?

Comment: @MattMorgan ```data``` just logs a success string, ```refetchNotifs``` is the ```refetch``` function from ```useQuery``` as a prop

Comment: Try using `useLazyQuery`